# ggstatplot: Pairwise comparison - how to display boxplot only, without violin plot?

Tags: violin-plot, pairwise.wilcox.test

I created a plot of pairwise comparisons using ggwithinstats.
This plot contains a box and violin plot.
I want the plot type to be only "box" but I cannot find this option.
What can be done?
Thanks!

[image]